# Reverted transaction and lost Eth of .05 during NFT sell out

Tags: go-ethereum, etherscan, contract-debugging

I was buying a "Panda Dynasty" NFT during the sale Saturday and they ran out of Pandas. It says  "Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Reverted]", but I was never sent my Eth back. I tried sending a 0Eth transaction to myself with a Nonce of 3, but that didn't help either.  What can I do? Thanks for anyone who helps out.

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x4fb506a34acc7bcd7c1e70125b0ace3d735901e5959cb89aedcb00ada2f0328b

Answer (score 3):

Please check your account balance carefully again. If the transaction reverted then your 0.05 ether could not have left your wallet. However, you still pay some transaction fees (in your case 0.00307 ether) and this is non-recoverable.